# Formatting TimeSpan to show only the relevant time unit

Tags: c#, .net, date, timespan

My application shows an estimated time for completion (ETA).

I don't want to give users a fully formatted `TimeSpan`, but showing only the most relevant unit. Users don't want to see **0:00:39,766**.

For instance, if the `TimeSpan` is

- 12 days, 5 hours, 42 minutes, 15 seconds

I would like to be formatted as "12 days"

If the `TimeSpan` is

- 5 hours and 3 minutes

it should only show "5 hours", because the amount of hours, compared to the minutes, makes the amount of minutes irrelevant.

The same for minutes. 15 minutes and 15 minutes and 3 seconds should be formatted the same way.

Is there an standardized way to do this?

Comment: There's no standard way, you're going to need a bunch of `if` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no *standard way* but you can implement an *extension method*:

```
 public static partial class TimeSpanExtensions {
   public static string ToMyFormat(this TimeSpan ts) {
     return ts.Days != 0 ? $"{ts.Days} days"
          : ts.Hours != 0 ? $"{ts.Hours} hours"
          : ts.Minutes != 0 ? $"{ts.Minutes} minutes"
          : ts.Seconds != 0 ? $"{ts.Seconds} seconds"
          : $"{ts.Milliseconds} milliseconds";
   }
 }
```

And then use it:

```
 TimeSpan test = new TimeSpan(0, 415, 48, 44, 452);

 // 17 days (415 = 17 * 24 + 7 - 17 days 7 hours)
 Console.Write(ts.ToMyFormat());
```